# Doing the heavy lifting, no gratitude

Tags: colleagues, team, conflict, teamwork

I have been in a very strange situation recently. 20 years of experience have had some disagreements conflicts in the past, but I have never managed to alienate a whole team towards me so far :) So it is kind of a new heights :D

The situation is the following, I am a contractor and have worked for particular orgamization 7+ years, so it has been kind of a long contract. I switched departments and ended up in a fresh new team, no-one except the manager has as long experience with the organisation as myself. Now the funny thing is that I noticed a major architecture error that the team was doing, applying orchestration in a situation where choreography is the first choice. How do you orchestrate lambda functions in a complex process? Not that it is impossible, just difficult. So I pushed them towards choreography and then everyone became passive and now I am pretey much doing the whole job. I tryed to involve them, to no success. On top of that the previous architect has chosen event buss to the architectural choice. So I kind of saved them double time. How do you do orchestration over event bus? And no one is grateful everyone is passive and waiting for me to do the job.
I am miserable.

What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: This is a rant... What is the actual problem?

Comment: "What am I supposed to do"  Have you asked your manager?

Comment: Passive agressive team. Agree to my proposals and then leave them to me even though they affect the whole team. I made a critical decision (the team made it based on my input)to push towards orchestration then I need to implement like half of the project on my own. And then if something goes wrong I take all the responsibility.

Comment: I dunno... I guess this is what you get paid for? Did you get management buy-in? Who directs these people and has this been given to them as one of their responsibilities or tasks? Your question sounds like a rant and sour grapes. I don't see an answerable question.

Comment: I'm opening this question, it's a common enough situation.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this situation many times. Most high level contractors probably do as well once they work with a team that doesn't know and respect their abilities.

You're not looking at it properly, and you're allowing it to impact your morale.

Just buckle down, do what is necessary and don't expect others to assist unless they're forced to. Whether it benefits the company or not makes no difference to the workers, it's just extra short term work and upskilling for them and it's not their company. You can expect anything from passive resistance to sabotage attempts depending on the people. But never expect them to get behind you, that would just be a bonus.

You may get some praise when it's all finished and proving itself valuable. But thats unimportant. If applause is what you need, go into showbiz.

You just factor in the people like everything else in the project. Some will be ornaments, some will be assets, some will be liabilities. There is nothing to get upset about. You will find the further you get into a project the more attitudes will change because most people want to be part of a sucessful outcome.

Most of the resistance you're noticing is because they don't trust the project to be sucessful, at the moment it's just one unproven architect changing what another architect did and creating waves. Was the first architect incompetent? The second? Let's wait and see. We'll put our names all over it when it looks like it's going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself - you are a Contractor.

You have 2 options in that case:

1: Collect all the CYA (Cover Your Ass) material you can, make sure your requests are made in writing and make sure any refusal(s) are made in writing, then keep billing your hours and collecting the $$$

2: Look for a new Contract.

Comment: billing billing billing. too bad the money has never been my main driving force.

Answer (score 1):

This is ALL you, once you understand this.  Stop wasting your good ideas on any team that doesn't value them.

You are expecting them to embrace your ideas as you do.  I am going to guess you've done this more than once.  I'm also going to guess that you're pretty good at spotting architectural patterns, and right now you're not doing that great in recognizing your own patterns.

Reiterating -- snap out of this idea that it's their duty to get 100% in line with your vision.  You're not the boss.  Peoples' motivations are different than your own.  If leading a team in this way is on your bucket list, you're in the wrong place.